# How harmful is VirtualBox extension pack?

Tags: usb, virtualbox

I would like my guest Windows access my external hard drive. When I try to install the VirtualBox extension pack, it warns me:

> You are about to install a VirtualBox extension pack. Extension packs
> complement the functionality of VirtualBox and can contain system
> level software that could be potentially harmful to your system.
> Please review the description below and only proceed if you have
> obtained the extension pack from a trusted source.
>
> Name:   Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack
>
> Version:  4.3.24r98716
>
> Description:   USB 2.0 Host Controller, Host Webcam, VirtualBox RDP, PXE ROM with E1000 support.

What harm can it do? I googled it but couldn't find any. Thanks.

Comment: Had it for some time, the 5.2 version. No issues observed.

Answer (score 1):

They are just being legally careful to make sure you know that you are installing software so get it from the right places.  It's super useful, go for it! (as long as you downloaded it from the official site)

Answer (score 0):

It's fine, but any time you are nervous about a system change you can use VirtualBox's built in snapshot feature.

1. shut down your guest OS
2. In the VirtualBox Manager, select your guest VM
3. On the upper right, select "Snapshots"
4. In the center, select the camera icon to take a snapshot of your VM
5. Give it a name like "Before Adding Guest Additions"

Then if everything goes pear shaped, you can easily roll back.